# Multiple Regex Matches Using Negative LookAhead

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the word "query" in the given string "The query resolution with this query management should not get highlighted. Only this query should get highlighted. "

using the following regex:

```
(query(?!\smanagement)|query(?!\sresolution))
```

But I'm unable to get the regex to match only the last word "query" in the string.

Regards,

Alok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `(query(?!\smanagement)|query(?!\sresolution))` regex fails to match only one `query` and matches all the 3 `query`s because you have two alternatives: `query` that should not be followed with a space and `management` and another alternative matching a `query` that is not followed with a space and `resolution`. You need to use one lookahead that will disallow both `resolution` AND `management`.

You can use

```
query(?!\s(?:management|resolution))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO8iX7/2)

The lookahead `(?!\s(?:management|resolution))` will fail the match of `query` that is followed with 1 whitespace followed with either `management` or `resolution`.

To only match whole words, use `\b`:

```
\bquery\b(?!\s\b(?:management|resolution)\b)
```

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/g60H8E) showing how you can get the first match in a string with this regex with `re.search`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'query(?!\s*(?:management|resolution))')
test_str = "The query resolution with this query management should not get highlighted. Only this query should get highlighted.The query resolution with this query management should not get highlighted. Only this query should get highlighted."
m = p.search(test_str)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I had another question. How do I get only the first match of the word "query" if it occurs multiple times in a sentence, using the code you provided ? I know we need to use "non-greedy" operator "?", but not sure where to put it.